# Arithmetical properties of certain recurrence relations

Tags: nt.number-theory, recurrences

Consider the following recurrence relation:

> $$(4i+6j+1)(2i+3j)a_{i,j}=3j a_{i+1,j-1}-2i a_{i-1,j}+32i(i-1) a_{i-2,j+1}, i\ge0, j\ge0,$$
>   $$a_{0,0}=1.$$

This equation appeared in the [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0944v1) (see pp. 21-23). The authors (V. M. Buchstaber, E.Yu. Bunkova) conjectured that (they observed this fact using computer)

> **Conjecture 1.** $$a_{i,j}=\frac{p_{i,j}}{q_{i,j}},\text{ where
> }(p_{i,j},6)=1, (q_{i,j},6)=1.$$

I observed using computer that

> **Conjecture 1.**
>   Moreover, $$a_{i,j}\equiv a_{i',j'} (mod\ 2^{n+1})\text{ for }
> i\equiv i'(mod\ 2^n)\text{ and }j\equiv j'(mod\ 2^n) (n=2\text{ is an exclusion}),$$
>    and 
>   $$a_{i,j}\equiv a_{i',j'}(mod\ 3^{n+1})\text{
> for }i\equiv i'(mod\ 3^n)\text{ and }j\equiv j'(mod\ 3^n).$$

Also I condsidered the equation

> $$(4i+2j+1)(2i+j)b_{i,j}=2i b_{i-1,j}-j b_{i,j-1}, i\ge0, j\ge0,
> b_{0,0}=1.$$

In this case we have the same property $b_{i,j}\equiv b_{i',j'}\ (mod\ 2^{n+1}\ )$ for
$i\equiv i'\ (mod\ 2^n)$ and $j\equiv j'\ (mod\ 2^n\ )$ ($n=2$ is an exclusion).

I tried to proved it, but I couldn't.  I understood that simple induction doesn't help. Also I proved using generating functions that

> $$ b_{i,j}=(-1)^ji!j!\sum_{l=j}^{2i+j}\frac{2^{l}\sum_{k=j}^{l}
> \frac{s(l,k)(-3)^{k-j}}{4^k}}{(2l+1)!(2i+j-l)!},$$

where $s(l, k)$ are Stirling numbers of the first kind (see [Wiki](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0944v1)). Unfortunately, my approach doesn't work for $a_{i,j}$.

P.S. Note that we can also construct other consequences like $a_{i, j}$ with the same property. For example, the consequence

> $$(2i+j)c_{i,j}=2i c_{i-1,j}-j c_{i,j-1}, i\ge0, j\ge0,
> c_{0,0}=1,$$

isn't interesting. ;)